# Reputation Notification Bug

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, notifications

I think I noticed a small bug when you gain reputation.

Here's how I found out:

I lost 5 reputation here on Meta, however I gained 10 reputation on StackOverflow. The two combined into 1 notification, so it said I gained 5 reputation which is irrelevant since the sites gained on were separate.

If this isn't a bug, please consider implementing a way to distinguish between different site reputation when notifying us? Combining the site changes doesn't quite make sense to me. Thanks!

(PS - I didn't know if this is a bug or a feature request, so please edit when determined!)

Edit: I know it distinguishes when you open the notifications bar, but before you click on it, it does not. That is what I'm talking about here)

Comment: This is working as intended, the number shown is your *network-wide* reputation since you last saw it.  As with most things, simply click for more detail.  Imagine if you have 3 or 4 sites, breaking it out in the bar itself would eat a ton of room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be by-design, as the header bar is now re-branded to display StackExchange, it means the inbox and rep notification labels are "combined" to notify you that there is a notification on any of the SE sites you are participating in.

Although it may be confusing initially to users, it shouldn't pose much of a problem than simply to let users know that their rep has changed on any/multiple SE sites.

A better solution might be to simply highlight/display the reputation button in a different color instead of displaying the combined rep change.

Comment: Re: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47515232 If you are going to proceed with marking previous questions as a duplicate of  the above-linked Question and Answer i.e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075421, then perhaps consider marking https://stackoverflow.com/q/47515232 as a duplicate of 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a/47172409#47172409, which provides the means by which to set the `.files` property at both Chromium and Firefox programmatically without using drag and drop

Comment: What do you mean? Why did you mark https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075421/setting-a-file-upload-field-value-javascript-jquery as a duplicate of the question where you posted an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a/47172409#47172409 resolves the inquiry until we get a `FileList` constructor defined by the specification. The question where you posted an answer is a duplicate of the above question and answer as well. Your present answer is incomplete

Comment: @guest271314 The answer on your question was updated *after* I posted my answer and dupe the other questions. Anyway I have edited the dupe targets on https://stackoverflow.com/q/39075421/584192, which you can do yourself as well.

Comment: If we are going to mark questions as duplicates relevant to the topic, the question where you posted an answer is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a as well. Whether or not the answer was posted after your answer is immaterial.

Comment: @Kaiido posted the gist of the present solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172409/, until we get a `FileList` constructor https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3269. When the SO ban is done will either mark Kaiido's answer as accetpted or post own answer. If we are going to mark all related questions and answers as duplicates, they should be marked as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a, which provides the means to set the `.files` property programmatically without user action

Comment: Note, the list of questions relevant to the topic is quite extensive. Have answered the question on several occasions previously before crafting a workaround. We could attempt to find all of those questions; if we are going to mark the inquiry as a duplicate, we can find and mark all of the questions concerning the topic as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a, instead of one at a time.

Comment: @guest271314 I crafted my answer specifically to answer drag-dropping of files, when the filelist is already available via an event (not how to create/get a filelist from a form). This is therefore not an exact dupe of your question. If you feel that the other questions have been incorrectly dupe closed, we can always edit the dupe targets.

Comment: From perspective here [How to set file input value programatically (i.e.: when drag-dropping files)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47515232) is an exact duplicate of [How to set File objects and length property at FileList object where the files are also reflected at FormData object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a) You still need to somehow get a `FileList` from somewhere - _"programmatically"_ to set the `.files` property. An existing `<input type="file">` `.files` property is not necessary.

Comment: That is if we are evaluating questions and answers to assess whether a question and answer is a duplicate of another, which you appear to have done at at least https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075421/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/.  @Kaiido's Answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172409/ includes working code and  link to the complete workaround https://gist.github.com/guest271314/7eac2c21911f5e40f48933ac78e518bd. The code at the OP itself at the above Question set arbitrary `File` objects at `.files` property using `Symbol.iterator` of `<input type="file">`